# MultiColumn DropDownList in Asp.Net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to show 2 columns in a DropDownList Menu. To accomplish that,

when I execute the following sql query in SSMS,

`"SELECT (convert(varchar,Cost_ID) +'   ,   '+ Item_Description) FROM Cost_ID"`

It brings the desired output. But when I add it in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Data-Source, i.e.,

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource12" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=MEHDI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PIMS;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT (convert(varchar,CostID) +'   ,   '+ Item_Description) FROM Cost_ID"></asp:SqlDataSource>`

it gives the following error when I run the program:

`DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Cost_ID'.`

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL statement doesn't provides a column name for your `CONVERT` operation:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT (convert(varchar,CostID) +' , '+ Item_Description) FROM Cost_ID"
```

Change it to:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT (convert(varchar,CostID) +' , '+ Item_Description) Cost_ID FROM Cost_ID"
```